# How do you update Scheduled Jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I have two scheduled jobs each running their own console application (.exe)

I updated the code for the executables and now I want to deploy them to Azure.  In the past I have deleted the old jobs and republished the new ones from scratch.

But I want to know is there a way to update the code without having to recreate the jobs and settings?

Answer (score 0):

you can use createorUpdate api to update your job, here is the sample code

```
public async Task CreateOrUpdateJobAsync(string jobCollectionName, string jobId, DateTime startDate, string recurrence, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var schedulerClient = new SchedulerClient(this.cloudServiceName, jobCollectionName, this.credentials);
            var job = new JobCreateOrUpdateParameters()
            {
                Action = new JobAction()
                {
                    Type = JobActionType.Https,
                    Request = new JobHttpRequest()
                    {
                        Body = "",
                        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {
                            { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                            { "x-something", "value123" }
                        },
                        Method = "POST",
                        Uri = new Uri(""),
                        Authentication = new AADOAuthAuthentication()
                        {
                            Type = HttpAuthenticationType.ActiveDirectoryOAuth,
                            Tenant = "",
                            ClientId = "",
                            Audience = "",
                            Secret = ""
                        }
                    }
                },
                StartTime = startDate,
                Recurrence = new JobRecurrence()
                {
                    Frequency = JobRecurrenceFrequency.Minute,
                    Interval = 1
                }
            };

            var result = await schedulerClient.Jobs.CreateOrUpdateAsync(jobId, job, cancellationToken);
          }
```